# Text in fancyhdr header moves up or down when multiple languages are used with relsize

Tags: fancyhdr, babel, relsize

I am using LuaLaTeX to typeset a Hindi-English dictionary. The Devanagari font I am using for Hindi needs to be scaled to match the heights of a normal glyph in the Devanagari script with that in the Roman script. For this, I use relscale every time there is Devanagari (there must be an easier way, but as the LaTeX code is programmatically generated, it is not a problem).

For the dictionary headers showing first and last word on the page, I am using the `fancyhdr` package with `\markboth`.

In the normal text, the scaling of Devanagari font works well and the baseline of the glyphs is aligned with uniform line spacing.

In the header, however, there is a problem. If the Devanagari has a glyph which goes below or above the baseline, then the whole header text (including Roman) is shifted up or down.

In this MWE, on the first and second pages, the baseline of the header text in Devanagari and Roman is at the same height in page. On the second and third pages, there is a difference. The whole header basline on page three is shifted down. Somehow the scaling is causing this problem.

How can this be fixed?

[image: Sample image]

```
\documentclass[twoside]{book}
\usepackage[showframe=true,top=22mm, left=18.15mm, bottom=27.25mm, right=18.15mm, paperwidth=129mm, paperheight=198mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[main=english]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\babelfont[english]{rm}{Charis SIL}
\babelfont[hindi]{rm}[Renderer=HarfBuzz,Script=Devanagari]{Noto Serif Devanagari}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}   
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\raggedbottom
\usepackage{relsize}
\begin{document}
\fancyhead[C]{\mdseries Hindi-English Dictionary}
\fancyhead[L]{\rightmark}
\fancyhead[R]{\leftmark}
\fancyfoot[C]{{\mdseries\thepage}}
\fontsize{10}{15}\selectfont

Some text

\pagebreak

{\leavevmode\markboth{\foreignlanguage{hindi}{\relscale{1.1}अग}}{\foreignlanguage{hindi}{\relscale{1.1}अग}}}\textbf{\foreignlanguage{hindi}{\relscale{1.1}अग} (aga)} = a mountain

{\leavevmode\markboth{\foreignlanguage{hindi}{\relscale{1.1}अग्रज}}{\foreignlanguage{hindi}{\relscale{1.1}अग्रज}}}\textbf{\foreignlanguage{hindi}{\relscale{1.1}अग्रज} (agraja)} = elder brother

\pagebreak

{\leavevmode\markboth{\foreignlanguage{hindi}{\relscale{1.1}अघ}}{\foreignlanguage{hindi}{\relscale{1.1}अघ}}}\textbf{\foreignlanguage{hindi}{\relscale{1.1}अघ} (agha)} = sin

{\leavevmode\markboth{\foreignlanguage{hindi}{\relscale{1.1}अघोर}}{\foreignlanguage{hindi}{\relscale{1.1}अघोर}}}\textbf{\foreignlanguage{hindi}{\relscale{1.1}अघोर} (aghora)} = not frightening, Śiva
\end{document}
```

Comment: check the log. You get a warning: `\headheight is too small (12.0pt):...`